# Unfolding a heading on same level as plain list, unfolds the plain list

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Assuming the structure:

```
* test 
   some text
   + test2
      some text
   * heading
     some text
```

After one cycle to the "test" heading the structure becomes:

```
* test
  + test2 ...
  * heading ...
```

However, once I have the cursor on "heading" and hit tab to cycle, it opens heading but it also opens test2!! Just like the above assumption.

Where I was hoping for this instead to happen:

```
* test
  + test2 ...
  * heading
    Some text
```

Only when running with emacs vanilla (-q) it does not bother unfolding any parent or same level heading/plain list.

I have a blank .emacs file, so it is nothing in my configuration that does this. Could someone help explain the reason?

Comment: Shot in the dark: you have two orgmode installations, one from emacs and one that you installed, and they’re getting mixed up.

Comment: Interesting.  I do indeed pin an org installation that is more up to date. I will research more. Thanks!